# Problem accessing div elements

Tags: javascript

```html
<div id="nav">
    <ul id="linkselect">
      <li class="important" ><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="rlsdoc.html" >Release Document</a></li>
      <li><a href="dtadmp.html">Data Dump</a></li>
      <li><a href="facsetup.html">Facility Setup</a></li>
      <li><a href="dbuelem.html">DBU Elimination</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to  put all the links (Home, Release Document etc) of div "nav" into a array so that I can iteratively use them. Please help me with the JavaScript code for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: be more precise when you ask a question : do you need the text or the link of the "a" node ? Or do you want the node ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need with pure JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var data = [];
    var oDiv = document.getElementById("nav");
    var links = oDiv.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
        data.push(links[i].innerHTML);
    alert(data.join("\n"));
};
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/zZhvR/).

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("a")
```

this will return a node list that contains all "a" nodes

Answer (score 0):

We could use a combination of `.querySelectorAll()` to query the desired anchors and `Array.prototype.forEach` to iterate over those static element references.

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('#linkselect a'),
    each    = [].forEach;

each.call( anchors, function( a ) {
    console.log( a );
});
```

Note: Both methods are not available in "old'ish" browsers, but are easily to create, lots of shims available.

Comment: This does not run in some browser, isn't it ?

Comment: @Jerome IE7 and below won't support the `forEach` for arrays, yep.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Javascript

```
var items = [];
var anchors = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0; i<anchors.length; i++){
    items.push(this.href);
}
```

jQuery

```
var items = [];
$("#nav a").each(function(){
    items.push(this.href);
});
```

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: yep. did not read properly. my bad :) [but jquery is amazing and does all wonderful things](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: lol @[linked post] - nice one! Anyhow, while I agree jQuery is good and great it's not Command of God.. sometimes good old plain JavaScript will be better to use. :)

Answer (score -1):

jQuery:

```
$('#linkselect li a')
```

plain javascript:

```
document.getElementById('linkselect').getElementsByTagName("a")
```

Comment: It does not select all "a" nodes but "li" nodes